Apache Flink HA - Selected leader wrong URL
having Flink cluster 1.19.0 with HA, asking zk "leader/resource_manager/connection_info" it shows the IP of the leader: neither localhost nor 127.0.0.1. It's the network accesible IP value.
Stopping Leader jobmanager manually, zk after the voting assigned to Leader Url:
pekko.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:44879/user/rpc/resourcemanager.

Of course none of the nodes in the cluster can connect to this Leader:
org.apache.pekko.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor           [] - Association with remote system [pekko.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:44879] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [pekko.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:44879]] Caused by: [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:44879]

Very very strange situation

Check jobmanager.bind-host & taskmanager.bind-host in your flink configuration file, just leave it or set 0.0.0.0.
Do not set node local ip for that.
